# Geth changing discovery port to 1024 shortly after start

Tags: go-ethereum, clients, validators

I'm running geth 1.13.14

My startup command is

```
./geth --port 30303 --discovery.port 30304 --http --http.api eth,net,engine,admin --authrpc.jwtsecret ~/myhex.hex --datadir='~/ethereum/execution/data
```

I'm also using prysm as my consensus client, the startup command is:

```
./prysm.sh beacon-chain --execution-endpoint=http://localhost:8551  --jwt-secret=~/myhex.hex --datadir='consensus/prysym' --suggested-fee-recipient=123 --checkpoint-sync-url=https://mainnet-checkpoint-sync.attestant.io/ --genesis-beacon-api-url=https://mainnet-checkpoint-sync.attestant.io/ --http-mev-relay=http://127.0.0.1:18550 --p2p-max-peers=30
```

When I run `admin.nodeInfo`, I see:

```
  ports: {
    discovery: 1024,
    listener: 30303
  },
```

I am able to change the port momentarily, but frequently see these messages in my geth logs:

```
INFO [03-26|13:50:43.171] New local node record                    seq=122 id=xyz ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30304 tcp=30303
INFO [03-26|13:50:43.171] Started P2P networking                   self="enode://xyz@127.0.0.1:30303?discport=30304"
INFO [03-26|13:50:43.172] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/execution/data/geth.ipc
INFO [03-26|13:50:43.172] Loaded JWT secret file                   path=/home/d myhex.hex crc32=123
INFO [03-26|13:50:43.173] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8545 auth=false prefix= cors= vhosts=localhost
INFO [03-26|13:50:43.173] WebSocket enabled                        url=ws://127.0.0.1:8551
INFO [03-26|13:50:43.173] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8551 auth=true  prefix= cors=localhost vhosts=localhost
INFO [03-26|13:50:50.059] New local node record                    seq=123 id=1234abc ip=xx.xx udp=1024  tcp=30303
```

I've tried rebooting my device. The one weirdish thing about this setup is that this device has two internal ips. I route all port forwarding to the ip connected to the LAN mac, the wifi mac has a separate ip. I used [this guide](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-eth/archived-guides/guide-or-how-to-setup-a-validator-on-eth2-mainnet/part-i-installation/guide-or-security-best-practices-for-a-eth2-validator-beaconchain-node) to setup my firewall.

There's nothing else running on the machine other than geth, prysm, and mev client. Anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Ideally, I'd like to have both discovery and listener on 30303 tcp/udp. If I do not explicitly specify the ports, the same issue happens and it automatically reverts to 1024 for the discovery.port.

Comment: Those logs look fine to me. Is the node erroring somewhere? You could check out someresat's blog too: https://someresat.medium.com/guide-to-staking-on-ethereum-ubuntu-prysm-581fb1969460